# How to remove pice0chop extensions from Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, malware, malware-removal

How do you remove Priceochop 3.9 and proiCechOpe 3.9 from Chrome?

Both show up in chrome://extensions and once plagued my browsing experience with advertisements.

Now they effectively do nothing as I've had several anti-malware utilities target them, as well as attempting to manually delete them by clicking the trash icon in extensions and also by deleting the associated files on my computer. But they still show up there every time I reboot my computer.

One curious thing is that when I load chrome for the first time after rebooting my computer it warns me to disable developer mode extensions, and I don't knowingly have any running, but I suspect it's those two that've got some higher permission so they can keep reinstalling themselves.

I've also tried scans with programs like Malwarebytes Anti-Malware, Hitman-Pro, and a couple others I cannot recall right now.

Answer (score 1):

There may be persistent module that re-installs extensions or there is issue with Chrome account sync.

Basically, free Avast Browser Cleanup can remove such extensions or you can use Extension removal feature of IObit uninstaller 4 (it is also free). AdwCleaner program is also useful.

http://www.free-uninstall.org/how-to-uninstall-remove-pricechop/